# CSRF detected error message on refreshing webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth-facebook, protect-from-forgery

I am working on a Rails application where details are fetched from facebook. I have fetched the details from facebook. But when I refresh the webpage I got an error called CSRF detected. I have used some methods but all of them have failed.

The facebook Graph API is used in edit action.

These were added in inside class of Employees Controller.

1. `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`
2. `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:edit]`
3. `protect_from_forgery :only => [:edit]`
4. `skip_before_action :authenticate_user, only: [:edit]`
5. `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!`

When authenticate_user is used(4th and 5th cases) I got an argument error,
`Before process_action callback :authenticate_user has not been defined`.

In all other cases, the error when refreshing the page just after updating the page using facebook was
`OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError`

`csrf_detected | CSRF detected`

PS: I have used 'omniauth-facebook' and 'koala' gem for the integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem earlier, I tried the verify authenticity token earlier but it only worked out when I redirected the page
So I request you to just redirect the page.

Answer (score 2):

do `redirected_to` to the page where the details needs to be printed.